Zohar and the 42 first letters of Torah
Sometimes it is said that 42 is the gematria of אהיה, but it is only 21. What is meant by that statement?  I only know about the ana bekhoach prayer.

Sometimes it is said... where?

אלו-ה is gematria 42.

I cannot findthe source back.

Diederik, (see) zie: https://inner.org/mathematics-on-the-parashah-%E2%80%A2-bo-%E2%80%A2-god-of-hosts/

Maybe you misunderstood the source, and it said that 42 is TWICE the gematria of that name. We can’t know for sure unless you show us the source.

The only connection between the title and the body of the question is 42

The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is 42.  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/for-math-fans-a-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-number-42/

@RabbiKaii Yeah. The title needs to have something to do with the question.

Think palindrome.
היהאהיה with the kollel is 42.
The principle is used often in Torah, like for example, during the rite of the sanctification of the new moon.

ואומר לחברו: שָׁלוֹם עֲלֵיכֶם: וחברו משיב עֲלֵיכֶם שָׁלוֹם: ג״פ

The letter 'Aleph' (א) corresponds to Commander of the World (אלופו של עולם) which is manifest as the Molad (the birth of the new moon), absolute nullification of self (בטול במציאות לגמרי היינו אין), when the visual appearance of the moon disappears completely for an instant. While the outer letters are moving toward the full moon on the 15th of the month (5...10...15)     (ה...י...וד׳ה).
The cycle of the moon is in general associated with the aspect of wife/female (נקבה או אשה) and so too is the name אהיה. In that context, the small sum gematria of the four Matriarchs, שרה, רבקה, לאה, רחל is also 42.
Just to point out, because it is not as obvious, one of the emphases from the structure of the palindrome is the general principle in the structure (עצמות היינו לשון צורה) of G-d’s universe that there is a right and left (חסד וגבורה שהוא קו ימין ושמאל היינו זה לעומת זה) also described as סובב או ממלא כל עלמין או חצוניות, which enclothes an inner aspect (פנימיות) also called קו האמצעי היינו הממוצא המחבר.
In that context, it is worth pointing out that this also works for יהוה with slight variation.
The palindrome is הוהיהוה and has a gematria of 42. But the kollel, the whole is not required. The sum is expressed naturally.
It also alludes to the creation of the concept of time and its evolution into how it is expressed in this world (עולם הזה).
The letter 'Yud' (י) corresponds to what is referred to was Unmeasured Time (זמן בלתי משוער) while the outer letters evolve and transform from past (היה) to present (הוה).
This name is associated with the aspect of male/husband (זכר או איש).
That male is פנימי to female and is enclothed within it. (זכר או דכרא הוא מתלבש בתוך הנקבה שהיא ענין הממלא וסובב)
In this context, the small sum gematria of the Patriarchs (אברהם, יצחק, יעקב) is 44.
This pertains to the traditional written portrayal of the 42 letter name that you mention.
It is usually written in 7 rows, corresponding to the 7 days of the week, comprised of 6 letters to each row. But the 6 letters of 7 rows are divided into 2 groups of 3 letters in each row for a total of 42 letters. So visually, the full name appears as two columns comprised of 21 letters.
If you included the count for the 2 columns to the 42 letters, it corresponds to the Patriarchs.
So the 7 rows of 6 letters forming 2 columns also corresponds to the 3 Patriarchs and the 4 Matriarchs together as 7.
And if you combine the small sum gematria for the Matriarchs and the Patriarchs, the resulting sum is 86 which is the name: אלהים, which is also  the gematria for הטבע, Nature, meaning the natural world comprised of the Heavens and the Earth
את-השמים ואת-הארץ,
which is a notarikon for the Shem Tov אהוה which is gematria 17.
And implied at the פנימיות of the notarikon for the center of the universe, like a soul enclothed within a body is the Commander of the Universe, the אלופו של עולם, the ‘Aleph’, but in a state of absolute humility and nullification of self,
הבטול האמיתי היינו אין סוף, ב״ה which is implied from the kollel for the whole Shem Tov אהוה itself, 17 plus 1, which is 18.
And this is:
חי אני נאום יהוה.
I am life, says G-d.
